# Como adicionar uma "constraint unique" em uma coluna sem apagar a tabela ou a coluna

Tags: postgresql, constraint, restrição-único

Essa é a tabela de exemplo

```
create table usuario(
    id serial primary key not null,
    nome varchar(100),
    email varchar(100),
    login varchar(100),
    senha varchar(100),
    tipo varchar(50),
    status varchar(30)
)
```

Eu utilizei esse código, mas não deu certo

```
alter table usuario add constraint unique_login unique(login)
```

Comment: qual erro q deu ?

Comment: Não deu erro, mas não adicionou a constraint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ola. eu tentei assim e deu certo:

```
alter table usuario add unique(login);
```

Comment: obrigado, deu certo

Answer (score 0):

os códigos

```
alter table usuario add constraint unique_login unique(login)
```

e

```
alter table usuario add unique(login)
```

estão corretos.
Testei os dois e ambos funcioram